# Submodules not clickable in github

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am using github and I have submodules in my repo. However, I would like to be able to click on the submodules on github to open the submodules repo page. This is my .gitmodules file.

```
[submodule "submodule1"]
        path = submodule1
        url = https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
[submodule "submodule2"]
        path = submodule2
        url = https://github.com/octocat/hello-worId
[submodule "submodule3"]
        path = submodule3
        url = https://github.com/octocat/hello-worId
```

[image: GitHub submodules]

Is there anything I can do to get the submodules clickable on github?

Comment: Does you `.gitmodules` contains BOM?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Never heard about BOM. I don't have it on .gitmodules ( the .gitmodules code is above). Figuring out what BOM is. Is it something I need for linking repos?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you do not have BOM (byte order mark) in your `.gitmodules` file? Your `.gitmodules` must **not** have BOM in order to be recognized by GitHub.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure. Is there a way for me to find out if .gitmodules have BOM? I am not able to find much help online regarding BOM. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Open file for edit in GitHub web interface and see if it have one extra character at the beginning of file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see any extra character when edit the file on the github. The .gitmodules looks the same as the one I shared even on github. fyi, when I clone the "parent" repo and do "git submodule init" and "git submodule update", it works fine. It clones everything. But, the problem is the link being broken only on github.

Comment: BTW, an easy way to check for BOMs that doesn't involve eyeballing things on web pages is to run `file .gitmodules` in a terminal (assuming you're on linux). If there's a BOM, it'll either say "Big-endian", "Little-endian", or "(with BOM)" somewhere in the description.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried "file .gitmodules" and I got ".gitmodules: ASCII text". So my .gitmodules definitely does not contain BOM. Any other reasons on why github links to submodules don't work?

Answer (score 5):

GitHub Enterprise does not link submodules that are not located on the same appliance, in the same way as GitHub.com does not link submodules that are not located on GitHub.com. So, linking does not work from github enterprise to github.com. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of trouble can be the directory separator:
If you add a submodule under windows you get an entry in your `.gitmodules` that looks like this:

```
[submodule "Source\\External\\Library"]
    path = Source\\External\\Library
    url = https://github.com/Username/Library.git
```

but for github to recognize the submodule you have to change it to this:

```
[submodule "Source\\External\\Library"]
    path = Source/External/Library
    url = https://github.com/Username/Library.git
```

Be careful not to change the first line, otherwise the entry will suddenly point to another (non-existent) submodule

Comment: While this was not the OPs problem it is a valid solution if you have added a submodule under Windows. So, on WIndows, after git submodule add, edit .gitmodules and change the path separator in the path = line to Linux standard / .

Answer (score 1):

Another case where submodule were not clickable if when their URL is a *relative* path (not the case in the OP)

This is no longer an issue in March 2021:

> ### [Hyperlink support for submodules with relative paths](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-19-hyperlink-support-for-submodules-with-relative-paths/)
>
> Submodules defined with relative paths are now clickable in the web UI, making it easy to navigate to linked repositories. Previously, only submodules with absolute URLs were clickable.
>
> Only relative paths following the format `../{repo}` (a repository with the same owner) or `../{owner}/{repo}` (a repository with a different owner) are supported.
>
> To learn more about submodules, see [Working with submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) on the GitHub blog.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but wanted to add another possible reason.

I faced the same issue. In my case I had used the SSH url:

```
git@github.com:<user-name>/<repo-name>.git
```

And this led to use the same URL in the .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "Project6"]
    path = Project6
    url = git@github.com:<user-name>/<repo-name>.git
```

After changing the url to following in the .gitmodules file

```
url = https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>
```