# Github - how do I create submmodules with web interface

Tags: github, git-submodules

I do not have much experience of Github and am learning all the time. I have three separate repos e.g.

- Cat
- Dog
- Animal

What I want is for them to remain separate but also for Cat and Dog to appear inside Animal. That means you can update Cat and Dog either in separate repos or when working on Animal Repo. So in the end I want

- Cat
- Dog
- Animal

  - Cat
  - Dog

I think this is called submodules. I am using the Github web interface, and can get files into it make releases and clone the repo. I cannot see a way where I can make subfolders using web interface. Can anyone help explain to me to how to do this via the web interface please?

Comment: Might it helps [Does GitHub have built-in support for submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035557/11021522)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Github - how do I create submmodules with web interface

That does not seem to be supported through web interface.

That is why, as a workaround, You would need to clone the repository `Animal` locally, and add your submodules with [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt):

```
git clone https://github.com/<me>/Animal
cd Animal
git submodule add https://github.com/<me>/Dog
git submodule add https://github.com/<me>/Cat
git commit -m "Add Dog and Cat"
git push
```

Then, and only then, would you see a reference to Dog and Cat repositories from the GitHub page for Animal repository, as seen with the question "[Submodules are not clickable in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36700992/6309)".

Comment: im not sure why this answer was accepted as it fails to answer the main point of question: "with web interface". the web interface does not support cli commands.

Comment: @unsynchronized I agree. I have edited the answer to make it clearer that such a feature does not seem available through GitHub web interface.